# What is the correct way dealing with background geolocation in Ionic?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, geolocation, capacitor

Which is correct to keep tracking user's location in the background or may be in app closed state.

I don't think [this plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation) works well.

Can I use capacitor [Background Task](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/background-task) and [Geolocation](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/geolocation) together to get better result. Or whether [Background Mode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode) helps. I'm building vehicle tracking application. Hence I need to collect coords of driving path.

Comment: Why don't you think the plugin works well? Have you read all the documentation for the plugin, there is useful info about Android issues including the info about promoting itself to a foreground service in order to continue to run in the background? I ask because I'm also interested in geolocation in Ionic - it would be better to get the plugin working than re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Beyan I'll go through the plugin again! I have just implemented whatever given in the docs but it wasn't capturing geolocation consistently.